# loan and interest rate

Tags: loans, interest

A loan payment of $4200 was due 3 months ago, and another payment of $1800 is due in 6 months from now. When should a single payment of 5800.00 be paid to settle the debt if interest is to be 2%?

Comment: We can't really answer this without understanding how the loan is amortized.

Answer (score 1):

Under the assumption that the payment of $1800 due in 6 months would have completely repaid the loan *if* the $4200 had also been paid 3 months ago.

Note this totals $6000 and you want to know when $5800 would repay the loan, so $5800 would have to be paid fairly early.

If the monthly interest rate is

```
r = 0.02/12 = 0.00166667
```

The principal to be repaid three month ago was $4200 plus the then-present value of $1800 (so discounted by 9 months)

```
4200 + 1800/(1 + r)^9 = 5973.22
```

[image: npv]

This is still greater than the $5800 you wish to repay the loan with.

To find the point in time when $5800 would repay the loan, solve the following

[image: npv2]

```
∴ x = 17.672 months
```

That is, 17.672 months prior to three months ago, so $5800 would have to have been paid 20.672 months ago.